# ¿Cómo mostrar la salida en el MainActivity si en la clase lo tengo con System.out.println?

Tags: java, android-studio

Por favor ayuda, necesito pasar la salida pero no tengo idea de como, ya intente quitar el `System.out.println`.

```
public void mostrarDatos()
{
    System.out.println("Codigo  :" + codigo );
    System.out.println("Nombre y Apellidos :" + nombre + " " + apellidos);
    System.out.println("Sueldo :"+ calcularSueldo());
    System.out.println("Lista de Cursos:");
    for(int i = 0; i < cursos.length; ++i)
    {
        System.out.println(cursos[i]);
    }
}
```

Y agregar el retorno, pero no tengo resultados , me pueden ayudar por favor, en el *MainActivity* se debería agregar y mostrar los datos, no en la clase

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Si solo quieres ver los resultados en consola puedes usar la clase `Log`. [Uso y ejemplos (documentación)](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-logcat?hl=es-419#WriteLogs)

Comment: Te refieres a que en vez de en consola, te muestre esa información en la pantalla de tu aplicación Android? Para eso tendrás que hacer un layout, colocar elementos visuales para mostrar los datos, y la lógica para obtener los datos y mostarlos en ellos.

Comment: No entiendo lo que deseas, si quieres ver la salida en el MainActivity me imagino que quieres mostrar los datos en algún control. Especifica por favor como y en donde quieres ver la información.

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que deseas es ver los resultador en la consola, puedes usar `Log.d`. Un ejemplo sería:

```
public void mostrarDatos()
{
    System.out.println("Codigo  :" + codigo );
    System.out.println("Nombre y Apellidos :" + nombre + " " + apellidos);
    System.out.println("Sueldo :"+ calcularSueldo());
    System.out.println("Lista de Cursos:");
    for(int i = 0; i < cursos.length; ++i)
    {
        Log.d("TAG", "resultado: " + cursos[i]); 
    }
}
```

A la hora de buscar tus datos en la consola solo haces lo siguiente, abres el `logcat` y escribes **TAG**:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cabe aclarar que el `String` **TAG** es el nombre con el cual lo buscaras, puedes escribir cualquier nombre siempre que recuerdes que debes buscarlo por ese nombre.

Comment: Muchas gracias, sabes como puedo verlo con el Toads, en el MainActivity, por favor ... aun trato de dominar el java

Comment: @999liz Pero "los quieres ver en el MainActivity"?, creo que no es muy clara tu pregunta, a que te refieres con "Toads"?

Comment: Asumo que se refiere a los `Toast`. Primeramente, ¿A qué te refieres con verlo en el `MainActivity`? Si estas depurando tu aplicación, sea en un emulador, adv o desde tu movil vía usb, lo único que debes hacer es crear un método que muestre tu `Toast` en donde sea que quieras que se ejecute. Ejemplo: `Toast.makeText(tuActividad.this, "Los datos en string", Toast.duracionLarga/Corta).show();` y no olvides maarcar la respuesta como correcta si te ha servido :)